# Contour lines for tile server at home?

Tags: openstreetmap

I am trying to set up an offline version of OpenStreetMap to use on holidays where internet can be spotty. Following https://switch2osm.org/serving-tiles/manually-building-a-tile-server-14-04/, I have managed to do so.

I am no wondering if there is any "easy" way to add elevation information? E.g. contour lines. My search on the internet has only revealed the guide (http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Contours), which seems a bit outdated. For example, it recommends using XML styles and does no. 
t tell me how to turn it into a carto style. Also I am unsure from it which approach is better Shapefile or PostGIS?

Does anybody know a better guide? Is there a better approach on how to add contour lines?

Comment: Not perhaps the answer you're looking for, but it seems worth mentioning (in case you're not aware) that the simplest way to get an offline OSM map (with contours) is probably to download one of the smartphone apps which does this for you. Locus Maps or Oruxmaps with Openandromaps works for instance.